# Writing to redis from dask workers

Tags: dask

Suppose I have a function that does some processing and store the result to a redis server

```
r = redis.StrictRedis()

def process(data):
    (...do some work...)
    r.put(...)
```

Now I have a large set of data, and I want to use dask to parallelize the process. Something similar to

```
from dask.distributed imoprt Client
client = Client()
for x in data:
    client.submit(process,x)
```

But I am getting `KeyError(<function process>)`. Any idea?

**EDIT**

It works according to @mrocklin answer below to place the connection initialization inside the function. I assume that the connection will be destroyed and recreated as workers come and go. Would it be more efficient if I rewrite my function to accept a batch of data.

```
def process(batches_data):
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    for batch in batches_data:
        (...do some work...)
        r.put(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess is that your object `r` doesn't serialize well.  This is fairly typical as objects with live connections often refuse to be serialized (with good reason).

Instead, you might try establishing the connection within the function

```
def process(data):
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    ... do some work
    r.put(...)
```

Additionally, I recommend that you hold onto the futures produced by `submit`.  Otherwise Dask will assume that you no longer care about these tasks and decide that it can ignore them

```
futures = [client.submit(process, x) for x in L]
wait(futures)
```

If this doesn't resolve your problem then I recommend editing your original question with a more complete exception and traceback.

Comment: Setting up/tearing down the connection within the function is so expensive that it just nullifies the Dask advatanges. In my case, a for-loop without Dask works faster. Is there a better way? Using connection pooling or some sort? I'd love to utilize Dask + Redis.

Comment: Yes creating a connection pool sounds like a great idea.  You might also want to batch up some of your work so that you use one connection for many entries.